# Emulator: ERROR: unexpected qemud char. channel close

Tags: eclipse

Whenever I try to launch an Android app it will cause this error:

> emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling
>   'com.hellos.ArithmaticCalculatorActivity activity launch'!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is a known emulator bug. Do you happen to be running Ubuntu?

Try deleting and recreating your AVD. If you're still having problems, try the following:

1. Try launching in several ways: by starting the AVD first from your
   list of AVDs, by right-clicking the project in your workspace, etc.
2. Click on Window-->Show View-->Other-->Devies, and click on the
   launched device, highlighting it. There is a known issue that
   sometimes robs your AVD of focus unless you do this.